# Physical Database and Log File location

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

How do I get the Physical Database and Log File location (file system path) of a DB in SQL Server 2005?

I used this to get the mdf file: {SELECT [Name], FileName FROM sysdatabases} but need to get the log file as well...

Cheers,
Conor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM sys.database_files`

Comment: Doesnt show where the log file is when I run this, only the filename path of the mdf file?

Comment: Opps you are correct I was querying the sysdatabases, sorry!!

Thanks

Comment: Interesting - this includes log files for me, and the docs (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174397.aspx) don't imply otherwise.

Comment: No problem - enjoy the system views!

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way

```
select * from sys.sysaltfiles
```

Comment: +1 - but watch out for this disappearing in a future version, sys.master_files is the recommended alternative to this view.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using sp_helpdb or sp_helpfile for this.

e.g:

```
sp_helpdb 'master'
```

Comment: Why?  Admittedly this provides some additional, potentially useful, information - but there's nothing wrong with querying the system views.

Comment: sp_helpdb reports wrong info against a snapshot, see here http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBAdmin/MSSQLServerAdmin/running-sp_helpdb-against-a-snapshot-sho-2008

Comment: Nothing wrong, until they move stuff around...  recently saw a problem where a query broke due to differences in 2000 and 2005.  Using the procedures would have avoided that problem.  Interesting about the snapshot breakage though.

Answer (score 1):

try this T-SQL Statement provides the logical name and the physical location of the data/log files of all the databases available in the current SQL Server instance:

```
SELECT db_name(database_id) as DatabaseName,name,type_desc,physical_name FROM sys.master_files
```

If you are using SQL Server 2000, you could execute the following T-SQL Statement:

```
SELECT db_name(dbid) as DatabaseName,name,filename FROM master.dbo.sysaltfiles
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following script to retrieve the data/log file names and paths:

```
declare @DBName                 sysname
        , @LogicalDataFile      sysname
        , @LogicalLogFile       sysname
        , @PhysicalDataFile     nvarchar(260)
        , @PhysicalLogFile      nvarchar(260)

set @DBName = '<database-name>'

-- Data file
select  @LogicalDataFile = name
        , @PhysicalDataFile = physical_name
from    sys.master_files
where   database_id = db_id(@DBName)
        and type_desc = 'ROWS'

-- Log file
select  @LogicalLogFile = name
        , @PhysicalLogFile = physical_name
from    sys.master_files
where   database_id = db_id(@DBName)
        and type_desc = 'LOG'

select  @LogicalDataFile as [@LogicalDataFile]
        , @LogicalLogFile as [@LogicalLogFile]
        , @PhysicalDataFile as [@PhysicalDataFile]
        , @PhysicalLogFile as [@PhysicalLogFile]
```

**Credit for the script goes to this blog entry:**
http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/davidwimbush/archive/2009/07/28/how-to-get-the-logical-and-physical-file-names-for-a-database.aspx

Comment: This does not work well when the database has many files, it could give you any of them. And one of them could be inside another folder. (

Comment: I see your point, I had only one data file, that's why I did not have any issues.